# maven: web.xml not read properly

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, war

I built an ear through maven. In my ear there is a war. the web.xml resides in the webApp.war/WEB-INF/web.xml. and it is packaged in war through war:war in maven. when i deploy on WAS 7 it gives me errors for the components listed in web.xml like :

> com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper    Servlet >SpringServlet is currently unavailable: SRVE0200E: Servlet    >[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]: Could not find required class -     >class
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/Spring-Context.xml             
            </param-value>     
        </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.go</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

it gives me three errors and two are servlets and one a listener.

One thing i should mention is that the web.xml has

```
   <display-name>CorpWeb</display-name>
```

while the webproject in maven is eCorp-web.

Will this be a problem.

Edit: also, the lsitener is present in the WEB-INF/classes and the other servlet is actually coming from a jar that is present in the ear/lib

(Sorry I cant put code blocks correctly only spaces cos when i load this site it says now : Stack Overflow required external JavaScript from another domain which is blocked or failed to load, Don't know what happened it was working two hours back...)
Thanks in advance
Syed...

Edit: I am sorry Aaron I cant add comments due to some kind of javascript issue: No the spring-web.jar is not in the WEB-INF/lib its in the root of the ear in the lib folder. I removed the libs from the war in order to make it a skinny war. Also, the error comes for a servlet as well which is present in the WEB-INF/classes folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `spring-web*.jar` is not on the classpath. Is it in the WAR in WEB-INF/lib?